# How to convert particular columns into rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to convert particular columns into rows. How can I do that? For example, I want to shift C2 to D1 and C3 to E1 in sheet 1. Below is the link for the same sheet:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GifSZqk9UXbne1CORGWEBTjm_ns_U9dI

Answer (score 1):

- In cell `D1` put formula: `=C2`
- In cell `E1` put formula: `=C3`
- Assuming you need this to do the same in `D4` and `E4` select range `D1:E3` and drag down.

[image]